# PostgreSQL: How to assign null value to variable within function's parameter list?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to assign null value to variable within function parameter list using PostgreSQL 9.3 version.

**Example**: My try

```
 create or replace function fun_para(a varchar(20) =null, dt timestamp =null)
 ...
```

ERROR:  input parameters after one with a default value must also have defaults

Comment: Exactly like that. What is the problem? This example works: `create or replace function fun_para(a varchar(20) = null, dt timestamp = null) returns void language plpgsql as $$ BEGIN END; $$;`

Comment: @ckruse, ERROR:  input parameters after one with a default value must also have defaults

Comment: Have a look at my answer to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have a parameter with a default value all following parameters have to have a default value as well. So this is valid:

```
create or replace function fun_para(a varchar(20) = null, dt timestamp = null)
returns void
language plpgsql as $$ BEGIN END; $$;
```

While this is invalid:

```
create or replace function fun_para(a varchar(20) = null, dt timestamp)
returns void
language plpgsql as $$ BEGIN END; $$;
```

This again is valid:

```
create or replace function fun_para(a varchar(20), dt timestamp = null)
returns void
language plpgsql as $$ BEGIN END; $$;
```

This is valid as well:

```
create or replace function fun_para(dt timestamp, a varchar(20) = null)
returns void
language plpgsql as $$ BEGIN END; $$;
```